# Can I reuse Scenarios in Specflow?

Tags: specflow

I have a Specflow Scenario like the following

```
Scenario: I Shoot a gun
When I pull the trigger
Then It should expel a bullet from the chamber
```

What I am wanting is to reuse this scenario like the code below

```
Scenario: I Shoot a gun till there are no bullets left
    Given I have a fun with 2 bullets in
    And I Shoot a gun
    And I Shoot a gun
    Then There should be no bullets left in the gun
```

At the minute I have to repeat all the steps in the Scenario I Shoot a gun like the following

```
Scenario: I Shoot a gun till there are no bullets left
     Given I have a fun with 2 bullets in
 When I pull the trigger
 Then It should expel a bullet from the chamber
 When I pull the trigger
 Then It should expel a bullet from the chamber
     Then There should be no bullets left in the gun
```

In this scenario above granted I am only saving 2 steps, but in my real life application I am saving rewriting around 20+ steps in some cases. I believe being able to call on a Scenario makes it far more easier to read and not have to worry about the hidden steps.

Is this possible in Specflow?

Comment: Do you mean re-use steps like "Given I have a gun with 2 bullets in"?

Comment: No Reuse whole Scenarios sort of like functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because I can't think of a reason why you want to reuse EXACTLY the same test more then once, I'm assuming you want to reuse the Scenario with different parameters. This can be done by using a Scenario Outline and Examples:

```
Scenario Outline: Person is supplying an address
    Given I am on the address page
    And I have entered /zipcode/ into the zipcode field
    And I have entered /number/ into the house_number field
    When I press nextStep
    Then I should be redirected to the confirmation page
Examples:
    | zipcode  | number     |
    | 666      | 1          |
    | 666      | 2          |
    | 666      | 3          |
    | 555      | 2          |
```

(the /'s in "/zipcode/" and "/number/" should be the '<' and '>' symbols)

Comment: Imagine you have a booking confirmation system that has 20 steps. I want to test step 20 does something particular if I enter an invalid value at step 1, but I don't really care about the inbetween steps 2 through 19. I want to be able to say

I enter dodgy data for step 1.
<I call a scenario which does steps 2-19>.
I check the data at step 20. 

this is a made up example, but kind of what I want to do. I have already written a scenario that will be for steps 2-19 so why would I want to rewrite all 18 steps again to do what my scenario is doing?

Comment: I understand I can do this several different ways, like in your example where I write a scenario with all 20 steps and then plug in different example data. I know this, but just wanted to know if it was possible to call scenarios as documentation is quite sparse with specflow

Comment: What I would do is create 1 step that performs steps 2-19 from the different scenario. Something like 'And the data is processed' where you call all the methods necessary to perform all those steps. So you only have to call 'And the data is processed' where you want those step 2 till 19 to be performed...

As far as I know, the solution you want (something like 'And scenario x is performed', where a complete scenario straight from the .feature file is read) is not possible...

Comment: Thanks Timothy, I thought as much. Yeah I have tried doing what you suggested, where i call each individual steps code passing in hard coded values to them all. As i was doing it thought surely i must be able to call a scenario itself if i want to keep repeating the same steps etc. oh well, maybe if more people pick it up it will be requested in the future

Comment: Well, I hope so. I have some good use for such functionality ;-)

Comment: Thanks Timothy, Have marked your answer as the accepted answer as it is the closest solution to what I was after and will probably be what most people are after. If anyone wants a little more information on Scenario Outlines, here is a link to the Spec Flow documentation for it

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Scenario-outlines

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you want the ability to say:

```
Scenario: I Shoot a gun till there are no bullets left
    Given I have a fun with 2 bullets in
     When I shoot the gun 2 times
     Then There should be no bullets left in the gun
```

You can call steps from within another step. You can see this in the step definition for *"When I shoot the gun 2 times"* :

```
[When(@"I shoot the gun (*.) times")]
public void WhenIShootTheGunNTimes(int times)
{
    // Fire the gun the specified number of times.
    for ( int i = 0; i < times; i++ )
    {
        // Call the other two steps directly in code...
        WhenIPullTheTrigger();
        ThenItShouldExpelABulletFromTheChamber();
    }
}
```

It just calls the other steps the number of times you specified in the gherkin. I chose to call the methods directly in C#. You may alternatively, call them indirectly using the gherkin as specified [here](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Calling-Steps-from-Step-Definitions).